# JS Error Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, silverstripe

I was running my website built using Silverstripe 3.0 on Codero WHM and everything was running fine. Now I got a situation where I had to move my website from Codero WHM to Amazon AWS Cpanel.

I have installed my website successfully and it is running fine but there is an error when admin side is loaded. When page is reloaded there is no error and everything works fine but when I navigate to other parts like settings or dashboard via ajax I get a JS error

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node.
fragment.appendChild(script);
```

I have no idea from where is this error coming from and how can I fix that. Please help me.

Comment: How the `script` variable is defined?

Comment: That doesn't' look like a silverstripe error that I've seen

Comment: @Artyom Nuestroev, script is defined like a node. For example `<div class="my-class">` and it gets defined many times based on the needs in SilverStripe. You can find the code in `assets/_combinedfiles/lib.js` which is a combined file of many js files mentioned in `framework/admin/code/LeftAndMain.php`. I have not seem any such error like that before. The same copy is working fine on other server, but not working when I moved to AWS.

Comment: @Barry Yes that is strange. I agree with you as I too have not seen such error before. I scratched my hairs off while trying to get this fixed. The same copy is working on other Codero WHM server but not working after I copied over the same webiste files to Amazon AWS.